# Mongoid 3.1 Querying Syntax Issue in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, mongoid, criteria

I have a Ruby Association class as follows:

```
class Association
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :issued, type: Integer
  field :lifetime, type: Integer
end
```

And I want to delete all of the docs in my collection where `doc.issued + doc.lifetime > Time.now`. I found the following syntax on the web:

`Association.delete_all(["issued + lifetime > ?", Time.now.to_i])`

I can't get this to work and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:298:in `[]'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.1.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:298:in `delete_all'
    from (irb):77
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this syntax or suggest different syntax that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**delete_all**, like **where**, needs a [list of conditions](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html) on single fields, like :

`Association.delete_all(issued: 10)`

In your case, you can use Javascript.

`Association.for_js("(this.issued + this.lifetime) > ti", ti: Time.now.to_i).delete_all`

Note : the performance won't be excellent, because the condition will be tested on each document.

Comment: This should work. In my real implementation, issued is a DateTime. Can I call this.issued.to_i in this answer, or would I need to move it to an outside variable like ti?

Comment: "(this.issued + this.lifetime) > ti" is a Javascript instruction, not a Ruby one. So you can only use Javascript functions, therefore this.issued.to_i won't work. and you can't be moved outside since you want to keep the variable.